# Lead and Opportunity Conversion

Tags: opportunity, leads

I have created record types, Customer and partner for both lead and opportunity. what should be done to convert customer lead only to customer opportunity as well as partner type lead to partner type opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly map a record type from lead to opportunity(Salesforce stores record type Id on the object which is different for lead and opportunity even when the record type names are same)

As a workaround map text field from lead to opportunity which stores record type name and then create a workflow on the opportunity to populate the actual recordtypeId.

**Follow these steps**:

1. Create a 'Lead Custom Formula Field' with a return type of Text:

   - Name the field (for example Lead Record type (Conversion))
   - You also have the choice to leave it on the page or make it a hidden field
2. Create an 'Opportunity Custom Text' field:

   - Name the field (for example Opportunity Record type (Conversion))
   - You also have the choice to leave it on the page or make it a hidden field
3. Setup Lead field mapping:

   - Navigate to Setup | Customize | Leads | Fields | Map Lead Fields button
   - Map the new 'Lead Custom Formula' (Text) Field to the new 'Opportunity Text' field
4. Create a 'Workflow Rule' on Opportunity:

   - To do this, navigate to Setup | Create | Workflow & Approvals | Workflows
   - Click New
   - Name the workflow and then select the Evaluation Criteria to be created
   - Add the 'Rule Criteria' as:
     Opportunity Record type (Converted) Equals
   - Add a field update to your workflow that will update the standard 'Opportunity' record type field to the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that. You can follow below blogs:-

1. [Assign a Specific Opportunity Record Type During Lead Conversion](https://jenwlee.com/2016/07/19/assign-a-specific-opportunity-record-type-during-lead-conversion/)
2. [Map Lead record type to Account record type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326268&type=1&mode=1)
3. [Solution for Mapping Lead Record Types](https://www.salesforceben.com/solution-mapping-lead-record-types/)

Highlights:-

1. Create a custom formula field on the lead object to determine the
   opportunity record type ID custom label for a given lead record
   type. Note: This can also be accomplished using custom settings, but
   custom settings get wiped out with each refresh so you need to put
   the custom setting record back into the environment. It is too bad
   that you can’t reference custom metadata type in a formula. That
   would’ve been my preference. LOVE, LOVE custom metadata types!
2. Use process builder to update the opportunity record type when a
   lead with a specific record type is converted.